# How to check a specific domain request with HTACCESS and add some query string?

Tags: htaccess, cookie, url-parameters, request

Is it possible to check a specific domain request with HTACCESS and add some query string?

Actually my entire task wants to pass some cookie values as URL parameters if a specific domain is requested.

Example:

- IF requested `OtherDomain1.example`

  - IF cookie named `TestCookie1` is set (a browser cookie 
    created with help of Javascript)

    - add `TestCookie1` value to request 
      URL `OtherDomain1.example` as parameters
      (`OtherDomain1.example?q=TestCookie1-value`)

so every request to `OtherDomain1.example` from my Apache server is rewritten by adding some URL parameters after reading the browser cookie.

If cookie is not set or cookie value is empty then nothing will happen the requested domain will work as usual no change.... if there any limitations to set else I am ok with passing empty query strings...

And if the domain is requesting with a URL-Path then that also needed to transfer...

Comment: What should happen if the cookie does not exist (or does not have a value)? Do nothing? Or still redirect but with an empty value? What about the URL-path? Only the document root or any URL-path? Does the URL-path also need to be transferred?

Comment: What is `TestOtherDomain1` is requested without any parameters?

Comment: @MrWhite the URL-path also needs to transfer just like normal but if the cookie exist just bring it that too...
And if the Cookie is empty or not exist or no value then nothing will happen the request will work as usual, and if there is any limitation I am ok with passing empty parameters if no cookies...

Comment: @StephenOstermiller sorry got some mistake in the example domain, Question just updated.
OtherDomain1.example is the external site domain and for my case, my URLs to OtherDomain1.example are currently not passing any parameters all hyperlinks just passing with URL-Paths...  But I think it would be good if there is an option to check and do needful append...

Comment: So, (from your updated question), there is only 1 domain here - you are redirecting back to itself?! "OtherDomain" is really just _this domain_? Although your comment above does imply 2 domains? ... "OtherDomain1.example is the **external site domain**"? Is "OtherDomain1.com" under your control?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes only one domain, that is just an example I used to represet a specific external site domain... so if any request comes to this specific domain then my server wants to add some parameters with the target URL. A request can be a hyperlink from my website to external website...

Comment: Sorry, still not sure that I follow... reading the cookie and appending this as a URL parameter on _the same domain_ doesn't really make that much sense. The site can already read the cookie (and URL parameter), so what does this achieve exactly? I could perhaps understand this if the inbound request to `example1.com` (for which the cookie was set) needed to be redirected to `example2.com` - you could then pass a URL parameter in order to be able to set a first person cookie with `example2.com`. (?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @MrWhite, here I didn't mention what is my domain and I only explained about an external domain request.
Just assume like this: MyDomain1.example  is my current domain and OtherDomain1.example is one of an external domain so Our Server that belongs to MyDomain1.example check if there is any request to OtherDomain1.example and do remaining...

Comment: So the DNS for both domains points to your server and your server is configured to server both domains from the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

> `MyDomain1.example` is my current domain and `OtherDomain1.example` is one of an external domain so Our Server that belongs to `MyDomain1.example` check if there is any request to `OtherDomain1.example` and do remaining...

I still think I'm missing something here? It sounds like you are wanting to intercept and modify the request coming *from* your site `MyDomain1.example` (or rather, the client's browser when looking at your site - I assume) *before* it reaches `OtherDomain1.example`, which is presumably a domain out of your control?

This isn't something you can do in `.htaccess`. Using `.htaccess`, you can only intercept the request at the destination, ie. `OtherDomain1.example` - but the cookie presumably isn't set for `OtherDomain1.example`?

This sounds like a task for JavaScript - to modify the outbound anchors in the HTML source before (or "as") the user clicks on them?

Or, is the scenario different to this?

---

Backtracking...

How your question was initially written seemed to make more sense. Along the lines of...

1. User sends request to `MyDomain1.example`, for which a cookie (eg. `TestCookie1`) has previously been set. Consequently, the user's browser sends the cookie as part of the request.
2. You wish to redirect the users request to `OtherDomain1.example`. You need to also forward the value of the cookie sent on the request to `MyDomain1.example` as a URL parameter (since the user does not have a cookie set for `OtherDomain1.example`).

This could be done with something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain1\.example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:\bTestCookie1=([^;]*))?
RewriteRule (.*) https://otherdomain1.example/$1?q=%1 [QSA,R,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable is not required if this is the only domain hosted at this server.

The condition that checks against the `HTTP_COOKIE` server variable (the HTTP `Cookie` header as sent by the browser) either matches `TestCookie1=<anything>` anywhere in the cookie header or "nothing" at all - either is considered *successful*. The cookie value is captured and this is passed through to the *substitution* string in the `%1` backreference. the original URL-path on the request is passed through to the target URL in the `$1` backreference. The `QSA` flag allows any additional query string parameters on the initial request to be passed through also.

However, this redirects *every* request sent to `MyDomain1.com` to `OtherDomain1.com`.

(Although, this may be answering a question you didn't even ask?!)